# Input checkbox not firing javascript for data-theme attribute

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to accomplish a few things to get dark mode working on my site.

1. Use a checkbox to switch between light and dark themes (the checkbox will set the `data-theme` attribute to user's preference). Here't the js below

   ```
   function detectColorScheme() {
    var theme="light";    
     //default to light

    //local storage is used to override OS theme settings
    if(localStorage.getItem("theme")){
        if(localStorage.getItem("theme") == "dark"){
            var theme = "dark";
        }
    } else if(!window.matchMedia) {
        //matchMedia method not supported
        return false;
    } else if(window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)").matches) {
        //OS theme setting detected as dark
        var theme = "dark";
    }

    //dark theme preferred, set document with a `data-theme` attribute
    if (theme=="dark") {
        document.documentElement.setAttribute("data-theme", "dark");
    }
    }
    detectColorScheme();
     //identify the toggle switch HTML element
         const themeSwitch = document.getElementById('hm-theme-switch-toggle');

    //function that changes the theme, and sets a localStorage variable to track the theme between page loads
    function switchTheme(e) {
    if (e.target.checked) {
        localStorage.setItem('theme', 'dark');
        document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'dark');
        themeSwitch.checked = true;
    } else {
        localStorage.setItem('theme', 'light');
        document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'light');
        themeSwitch.checked = false;
      }    
     }

      //listener for changing themes
        themeSwitch.addEventListener('change', switchTheme, false);

   //pre-check the dark-theme checkbox if dark-theme is set
       if (document.documentElement.getAttribute("data-theme") == "dark"){
       themeSwitch.checked = true;
    }
   ```
2. My html and css is setup that I have a pseudo element to change the text if the checkbox is checked, along with the entire theme changing to dark mode. For some reason it's not firing though even though I have the label pointed to the input id and the correct id is called in js.

   ```
   <div class="hm-theme-switch-wrapper">
        <input type="checkbox" class="hm-theme-toggle" id="hm-theme-switch-toggle" name="hm-checkbox" />
        <label for="hm-theme-switch-toggle" id="hm-theme-switch" style="text-align:right;"><i class="hm-theme-state-icon"></i><span>Dark</span></label>
    </div>

    .hm-theme-switch-wrapper {
        background-color: none;
        border-radius: 150px;
        border: 2px solid var(--hm-color-text);
        overflow: auto;
        float: right;
        width: 100px;

    label {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        margin: 0;
    }

    input.hm-theme-toggle {
        display: none;
    }

    input#hm-theme-switch-toggle:checked + label span {
        display: none;
    }

    input#hm-theme-switch-toggle:checked + label:after {
        content: "Light";
    }

    .hm-theme-state-icon {
            background-image : url(https://michaelcraig.design/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/light_dark.svg);
            background-size: cover;
            display: inline-block;
            height: 20px;
            width: 20px;
            margin-right: 10px;
        }
        .hm-theme-state {
            text-align:center;
               display:block;
            border-radius:4px;
            color: var(--hm-color-text);
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: 600;
        }

    }
   ```

I appreciate any help and suggestions. You can also view this live @ https://michaelcraig.design

Comment: Your `Console` should be showing you an error .. That *should* point you in the right direction ..

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null`

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/COM78iF

Comment: @Zak Ok, I fixed that part, was some extra stuff in the footer, but it looks to be unrelated. I'm still having trouble getting it to fire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try put this lines:

```
const themeSwitch = document.getElementById("hm-theme-switch-toggle");
themeSwitch.addEventListener("change", switchTheme, false);
```

.. inside a ready trigger:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  const themeSwitch = document.getElementById("hm-theme-switch-toggle");
  themeSwitch.addEventListener("change", switchTheme, false);
});
```

Maybe DOM is not ready when getElementById run.

Edit: Since OP is not using jQuery, here's the vanilla JS equivalent:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const themeSwitch = document.getElementById("hm-theme-switch-toggle");
  themeSwitch.addEventListener("change", switchTheme, false);
});
```

Comment: OP is not using jQuery. And you shouldn't, either, unless you know the DOM API by heart.

Comment: @cassiolacerda That seems to have done it. I noticed that on other pages it was working, but on the home page it takes a few minutes and throw a "can't find variable" error before it starts to work, it appears something is lagging, causing a delay by the time the script runs.